# GSSAPI operation failed with error - Linux Azure App Service

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am considering moving my app service from Windows to a Linux app service.
On the Linux app service I get the following error when I try to download a file.

" GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested. NTLM authentication requires the GSSAPI plugin 'gss-ntlmssp'."

I tried installing the gss-ntlmssp package on the app service but am not sure if it installed successfully and my downloads still fails afterwards

> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> gss-ntlmssp gss-ntlmssp-dev libwbclient0
> 0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
> Need to get 184 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 372 kB of additional disk space will be used.
> Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libwbclient0 amd64 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u3 [133 kB]
> Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gss-ntlmssp amd64 0.7.0-4 [47.6 kB]
> Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gss-ntlmssp-dev amd64 0.7.0-4 [3638 B]
> Fetched 184 kB in 0s (1854 kB/s)
> debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
> debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78, <> line 3.)
> debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
> debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
> debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7, <> line 3.)
> debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
> Selecting previously unselected package libwbclient0:amd64.
> (Reading database ... 14675 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../libwbclient0_2%3a4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u3_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u3) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package gss-ntlmssp.
> Preparing to unpack .../gss-ntlmssp_0.7.0-4_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking gss-ntlmssp (0.7.0-4) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package gss-ntlmssp-dev.
> Preparing to unpack .../gss-ntlmssp-dev_0.7.0-4_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking gss-ntlmssp-dev (0.7.0-4) ...
> Setting up libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u3) ...
> Setting up gss-ntlmssp (0.7.0-4) ...
> Setting up gss-ntlmssp-dev (0.7.0-4) ...
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10+deb10u1)

Comment: What is the `framework / version` of your Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the delayed response here.

I’m not sure if you’re leveraging blessed image/custom container.

“gss-ntlmssp” library is not installed by default on some App Service blessed images, you may try the following steps (if you haven't tried already so):

1. Install the missing dependency “gss-mtlmssp” and then run the dll in the startup command as mentioned below ( example for dotnet):

   ```
         apt-get update $ apt-get install -y –no-install-recommends gss-ntlmssp && dotnet exec <yourappdll>
   ```
2. You may run this startup command by directly adding it under the Configurations.

Or run the startup commands via startup file. You may add the cmdlet mentioned (above) installation commands in a startup.sh file and place it under the /home folder from the Kudu site (https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/).

Please checkout these docs for the steps:
[Create a startup file -as an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/python/configure-python-web-app-on-app-service#create-a-startup-file) and [App Service Linux FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json#what-are-the-expected-values-for-the-startup-file-section-when-i-configure-the-runtime-stack-)

Comment: FIY adding `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gss-ntlmssp` in a Dockerfile fixes the same issue when using containers to deploy a Dotnet app. Thanks !